# how to add includes in native c code that will be compiled by android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

can someone give me a guide on how I can add headers to my native c file.

So here's the details.

I was able to setup my android project to call a native function from a .so file. And actually I need to add box2d to my project, but I when I include the header files, it won't make. So basically my problem is how do I tell the make file to include a whole folder with header and cpp files.

I tried adding the path directly to the include statement just for the sake of testing it. The error goes away, but new errors come out.

Can anyone give me a simple guide how I to do this?
Or what lines in the android.mk file should I add?
I've been struggling for a week now, and other tutorials are really not that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about posting the specific errors you're getting? Without them, it's a bit tricky to pin-point your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which includes you're trying to make, but the ndk does not support the standard libraries.  Try using this instead:

http://www.crystax.net/android/ndk-r4.php